# Rust do calculations at compile time

Tags: rust

I want to calculate sin of 30° at compile time. It should be a constant in my code. Is there an easy way to calculate it when compiling.

```
const SIN30: f32 = (PI / 6.0).sin();
```

Comment: You could just use [once_cell](https://docs.rs/once_cell/latest/once_cell/). Not compile-time, but is static for the lifetime of the program.

Comment: Floating point arithmetic in constants is currently [WIP](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/57241) due to the subtle ways that floating point arithmetic may differ on the hardware that the program is compiled on vs. the hardware that the programs executes on. Since the calculation you reference is super-simple, you are probably best of computing it externally and store the result as a "hand-written" const.

Comment: What about `const SIN30: f32 = 0.5;`?

Comment: It's just a number, so you could presumably work it out and paste it in, though I think `once_cell` is the answer here. While it's run-time computed, it's only done once so the cost is marginal.

Comment: Awful idea: Do the calculation in `build.rs` and write it to a file. (Or well, a proc macro, if you're willing to make a package just for that.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

const evaluation of floating point arithmetic is [not stabilized yet](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/57241) at the time of writing.

If you need this specifically for the `const` part, then I understand your problem.

If this is purely for performance reasons, though, be aware that compilers are already [very good at compile time evaluation](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/n1qxEbcjf) even without the `const` keyword:

```rust
pub fn sin30() -> f32 {
    (std::f32::consts::PI / 6.0).sin()
}


pub fn sin30x2() -> f32 {
    sin30() * 2.0
}
```

```
.LCPI0_0:
        .long   0x3f000000
example::sin30:
        vmovss  xmm0, dword ptr [rip + .LCPI0_0]
        ret

.LCPI1_0:
        .long   0x3f800000
example::sin30x2:
        vmovss  xmm0, dword ptr [rip + .LCPI1_0]
        ret
```

Comment: Uhm I don't think `sin(60) == 2.0 * sin(30)`. Of course it dosen't take anything away from your point.

Comment: @cafce25 Damn :D you are of course right. Fixed